# Drop down list to filter rows on specific column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that filters a table depending on what you select in the dropdownlists. But right now it filters a whole row. I need each dropdownlist to filter a specific column.

I tried calling the `filter` function for each `option:selected` but that didn't work. I'm not sure how to approach this with the function that I already have.

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2dhE5/50/). I need the first dropdown to filter on the first column and the second dropdown to filter on the third column.
If you select `wood` and `green` it should only show the row that has `wood` in the first column and `green` in the third.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.filter').change(function () {
        var values = [];
        $('.filter option:selected').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != "") values.push($(this).text());
        });
        filter('table > tbody > tr', values);
    });

    function filter(selector, values) {
        $(selector).each(function () {
            var sel = $(this);
            var hide = false;
            $.each(values, function (i, val) {
                if (sel.text().search(new RegExp("\\b"+val+"\\b")) < 0) hide = true;
            });
            hide ? sel.hide() : sel.show();
        });
    }
});
```

html

```
<select class="filter">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="a">wood</option>
</select>
<select class="filter">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="1">blue</option>
    <option value="2">green</option>
    <option value="3">red</option>
</select>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Wood comes from trees</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>blue</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some wood is hard</td>
            <td>512</td>
            <td>green</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some people like woodwork</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Some wood is green</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>blue</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made some changes to Your example and it seems to work  [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lukaszewczak/2dhE5/52/)(**new version**) ,

I change filter method , and now method is checking how many times the word was found, hope this helps

**HTML** I add `data-col` atributes for select element for holding column index

```
<select class="filter" data-col="0">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="a">wood</option>
</select>
<select class="filter" data-col="2">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="1">blue</option>
    <option value="2">green</option>
    <option value="2">red</option>
</select>
```

And new js code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.filter').change(function () {
    var values = [];

     $('.filter').each(function () {
        var colIdx = $(this).data('col');

         $(this).find('option:selected').each(function () {
             if ($(this).val() != "") values.push( {
                text: $(this).text(),
                colId : colIdx
             });
        });
    });
    filter('table > tbody > tr', values);
});

function filter(selector, values) {console.log(values);
    $(selector).each(function () {
        var sel = $(this);
        var tokens = sel.text().trim().split('\n');
        var toknesObj = [], i;
        for(i=0;i<tokens.length;i++){
            toknesObj[i] = {
               text:tokens[i].trim(), 
               found:false
            };
        }

        var show = false;
        //console.log(toknesObj);
        $.each(values, function (i, val) {                

       if (toknesObj[val.colId].text.search(new RegExp("\\b"+val.text+"\\b")) >= 0) {
           toknesObj[val.colId].found = true;
          }

        });          
        console.log(toknesObj);
        var count = 0;
         $.each(toknesObj, function (i, val) {
             if (val.found){
                 count+=1;
             }
         });
        show = (count === values.length);        
        show ? sel.show() : sel.hide();
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you but this does not target the first dropdown to the first column or the second dropdown to the third column. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2dhE5/49/

Comment: Hmm You are right, so I make new version, i think that now this is it

Comment: Seems to be working =) I'll use this for now. Thank you!

Comment: Great solution. Quick follow-up question. Is there any way to have this account for `colspans`?